# TicTacToe implementation in Java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

Right now I'm studying Java, and as a part of understanding arrays, I've implemented a Tic-Tac-Toe game based on two-dimensional array.

Any suggestions/comments are much appreciated!

Source code will be below, also available in [GitHub repo](https://github.com/burtsdenis/tictactoe).

**Main.java**

```
package TicTacToe;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int x = -1;
        int y = -1;

        System.out.print("Enter name for player №" + Player.playersCount + ": ");
        Player player1 = new Player(reader.readLine(), "X");
        System.out.print("Enter name for player №" + Player.playersCount + ": ");
        Player player2 = new Player(reader.readLine(), "O");

        TicTacToe game1 = new TicTacToe(3);
        game1.initializeGame(player1, player2);

        while (true) {
            try {
                if (x < 0) {
                    System.out.print("Enter x: ");
                    x = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                }
                if (y < 0) {
                    System.out.print("Enter y: ");
                    y = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Your input is incorrect, value must Integer!");
                continue;
            }

            if (!game1.checkInput(x, y)) continue;
            if (!game1.turnAllowed(x, y))  { x = -1; y = -1; continue; }

            TicTacToe.turnNumber++;
            if (TicTacToe.turnNumber % 2 != 0) {
                if (game1.makeATurn(x, y, player1)) {
                    System.out.println(player1.name + " wins!");
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (game1.makeATurn(x, y, player2)) {
                    System.out.println(player2.name + " wins!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            x = -1;
            y = -1;
        }
    }

}
```

**TicTacToe.java**

```
package TicTacToe;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class TicTacToe {
    static int turnNumber = 0;
    String[][] gamingBoard;

    public TicTacToe(int n) {
        gamingBoard = new String[n][n];
    }

    void initializeGame(Player player1, Player player2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < gamingBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gamingBoard.length; j++) {
                gamingBoard[i][j] = "-";
            }
        }
        printGameBoard();
    }

    void printGameBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gamingBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gamingBoard.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(gamingBoard[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    boolean turnAllowed(int x, int y) {
        if (gamingBoard[x][y].equals("-")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Choose another field!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean checkInput(int x, int y) {
        try {
            if (x <= gamingBoard.length - 1 && y <= gamingBoard.length - 1) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);

        }
        System.out.println("Your input is incorrect, values must be between 0 and 2");
        return false;
    }

    boolean makeATurn(int x, int y, @NotNull Player player) {
        gamingBoard[x][y] = player.playingMark;
        printGameBoard();
        boolean winner = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < gamingBoard[i].length; i++) {
            if (!gamingBoard[x][i].equals(player.playingMark))
                break;
            if (i == gamingBoard.length - 1) {
                winner = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < gamingBoard.length; i++) {
            if (!gamingBoard[i][y].equals(player.playingMark))
                break;
            if (i == gamingBoard.length - 1) {
                winner = true;
            }
        }

        if (x == y) {
            for (int i = 0; i < gamingBoard.length; i++) {
                if (!gamingBoard[i][i].equals(player.playingMark))
                    break;
                if (i == gamingBoard.length - 1) {
                    winner = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (x + y == gamingBoard.length - 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < gamingBoard.length; i++) {
                if (!gamingBoard[i][(gamingBoard.length - 1) - i].equals(player.playingMark))
                    break;
                if (i == gamingBoard.length - 1) {
                    winner = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return winner;
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
package TicTacToe;

public class Player {
    String name;
    String playingMark;
    static int playersCount = 0;

    public Player(String name, String playingMark) {
        playersCount++;
        this.name = name;
        this.playingMark = playingMark;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Naming & Readability

Choosen naming mostly conveys purpose (expressive) and follows conventions (camelCase).

#### Design & Structure

Very good design for a learner:

- `TicTacToe` represents a *game instance* currently playing

  - having a `board` (composition) recording current *board state*
  - initializes game (*registering* 2 players, *resetting* board)
  - checks for allowed moves (target field on board and not occupied)
  - executes a player's turn and *evaluates* if turning player is a winner (horizontal, vertical, if indicated both diagonals in a row)
- `Player` represents one player (of minimum required 2), including his mark

Improvements:

- apply **information hiding**: public getters and setters allow access and modification of private member variables (take advantage of *Lombok*)
- UI invades gaming-logic! What about a separate `TicTacToeUI` class that is responsible for input (player name, moves) and output (render board, show winner), probably validation (check input). This concept is called **Separation of Concerns** (similarly also applied as **MVC**).
  Beneficial for a later extension, e.g from text-based input (TUI) towards graphical (GUI) or web-based using a REST interface.
- **Encapsulate round-based iteration** inside the game class. So `main` is just responsible for initiating and starting the game (additionally stopping, if an exit-handler may be implemented allowing a long game to be aborted). That is what the **Single Responsibility Principal** (SRP) suggests.
- split long methods like `makeATurn`: one `moveTo(player, x,y)` another `boolean hasWon(player, x, y)` which calls `evaluateHorizontal`, etc. (SRP) in order to check the rows separately.

#### Stability & Technical Improvement

- `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is not thrown in `checkInput`. Although it does not check for negative index values (which have a special meaning for the game-loop!)
- **magic numbers** like `-1` should be defined as *constant* to express purpose in their name
- although a class-variable like `static int playerCount` is possible (Beware: counts players of *all game instances*!), what's the purpose?
- `turnNumber` should not be static, but initialized within constructor

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer!
I'll continue to improve my code following your recommendations.

Comment: _Continue_ marks a favourable attitude! I will also improve my answer, if I have refinements to add.